# Search for records updated on specific date and time

Tags: jql

I am trying to pull tickets that were updated on a certain date at a certain time.  Specifically, i am looking for tickets that were updated on 8/17 between 3:15  pm ET and 3:20 pm ET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/how-can-I-create-a-filter-with-time-range/qaq-p/60951), you may try using a range:

```
project = some_project AND
    updated >= "2018/08/17 15:15" AND updated <= "2018/08/17 15:20"
```

Replace `some_project` with the actual name of your project.  If you are not performing this search from the ET timezone, then you'll need to shift the above timestamps.